# Flutter- understanding models

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i just wanted to ask since this thing got me confused, i am still beginner with OOP i started it with Java and now working with it in flutter, so basically when i use a model in flutter, am i using it to fetch data from an api or a web server, am i right? let's say it's like select .. from .. in SQL, is that right? for example here i have this model of location

```dart
import './location_fact.dart';

class Location {
  final String name;
  final String url;
  final List<LocationFact> facts;
  Location({this.name, this.url, this.facts});
}
```

so basically in `final name` and `final url` i am specifying which data to get from the api or the web server ( in the example i am just giving fake data which just data i am giving it manually without a third party api or web server ) so when i use these i am just like using select name, url from "apî" ? is that the deal here?  and when i am using the Location({this.name, this.url, this.facts}) am i specifying which data this model will take as a parameter ? and when i am using final am i like referring to the data that it won't be fetched again once it's fetched? and when i am using `final list <LocationFact> facts;` am i specifying that this data is going to take the facts only from the list or what? i know this is overwhelming but i am really beginner with dart and flutter generally, i appreciate anyone's help and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading too much magic into the word "model".  In the original "MVC" triad, there are Models (places to stash data), Views (basically Widgets in Flutter), and Controllers (generally buried in Widgets in Flutter, but can be and should be pulled out to testable and reusable logic).  Does that help?

Comment: Thank you Randal for your responsive, this really helped me, but what i am asking is the functionality of model when it comes to a simple widget, it fetch data to a mock right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you fetching data from `API` it will return data in `json` format as `json Object` or `json List` after fetching data from `API` you can use `json` data or you can convert `json` Object to `Plain Dart Object`

To convert `json data` to `Plain Dart Object` you have to specify your `model` class.

Here is an example to design a model class

```
class Location {
  String name;
  String url;
  List<Facts> facts;

  Location({this.name, this.url, this.facts});

  Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    url = json['url'];
    if (json['facts'] != null) {
      facts = new List<Facts>();
      json['facts'].forEach((v) {
        facts.add(new Facts.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    if (this.facts != null) {
      data['facts'] = this.facts.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Facts {
  String locationFact;

  Facts({this.locationFact});

  Facts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    locationFact = json['locationFact'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['locationFact'] = this.locationFact;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here `Location.fromJson()` is an `factory` method to convert your `json` object to  `Plain Dart Object`

For reference you should take a tour into the Official Documentation
[Fetch Data From Network Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Comment: Thank you so much, that really gonna help me through my flutter career for sure, but what i was asking is just something simple i am giving fake data which are data created by me, and i am just wondering of the functionality of the model

Comment: I got your problem. I will make an update in my answer.